# preload jQuery building of JSON results

Tags: json, jquery

So I am currently building an activity feed/news feed or sorts using JSON and jQuery (and of course PHP). Everything works really well, especially fetching new results. The only issue is the first load - and I'm wondering if there is some way to sort of preload the results to make it more slick?

jQuery code below:

```
for (var j = 0; j < jsonData.items.length; j++) {
  var entryData = jsonData.items[j];
  var entry = template.clone();
  entry.removeClass("template");

  entry.find(".message").text(entryData.statusid); 
  entry.find(".actName").text(entryData.name); 
  entry.find(".actContent").text(entryData.content);

  //get the users ProfilePic
  var profileImg = $("<img />");
  profileImg.attr("src", "./img/" +entryData.profilePic);
  profileImg.addClass("feed-user-img");
  entry.find(".actProfilePic").append(profileImg);

  //Get user-uploaded images.
  entry.find(".actImage").text(entryData.imageKey);
  if (entryData.imageKey != "") 
        {
          var img = $("<img />"); // Create the image element
          img.attr("src", "http://spartadev.s3.amazonaws.com/" + entryData.imageKey); // Set src to the s3 url plus the imageKey
          entry.find(".actImage").append(img); // Append it to the element where it's supposed to be
        }
  spot.prepend(entry);
  spot.find(".entry").first().hide().slideDown();
}
```

Comment: What's the issue with the first load?

Comment: Updated the code to show some more effects I am using. I am using .slideDown()  on the .prepend, which works great for each new entry, but not so great on first load when it loads all the entries.

Comment: if the first load comes late, you may want to fake it...

Comment: Sounds like what I want to do, any tips on what I should search for?

Comment: @user2656127 Is your feed a remote one or do you control the source? If you control the source you can initially load the feed using php and the rest with your javascript loop.

Comment: @hitautodestruct so, yes I control the source and use PHP to build the JSON array. But, wouldn't I lose the "templating" that I build in the javascript?

Comment: @user2656127 You need to have the same "templating" initially and then build your javascript on top of that.